# PHP/SQL syntax Error at line 1

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

The error I'm having related to the drop-down list:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '','100',' Progress ')' at line 1

```
<?php
session_start();
/* Database connection settings */
$host = '';
$user = '';
$pass = '';
$db = '';
$mysqli = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$db) or die($mysqli->error);
?>

<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') 
{
$FirstName           = $_POST['FirstName'];
$LastName             = $_POST['LastName'];
$Passport             = $_POST['Passport'];
$TeachersName         = $_POST['TeachersName'];
$Date                 = $_POST['Date'];
$CourseType         = $_POST['CourseType'];
$CourseCode         = $_POST['CourseCode'];
$Grammar               = $_POST['Grammar'];
$Reading               = $_POST['Reading'];
$Writing               = $_POST['Writing'];
$Listening               = $_POST['Listening'];
$Speaking                 = $_POST['Speaking']; 
$TeachersAssessment = $_POST['TeachersAssessment'];
$Totalz             = $_POST['Totalz'];
$Overallz             = $_POST['Overallz'];
$Progress              = $_POST['Progress'];
}

$Results = $Grammar + $Reading + $Writing + $Listening + $Speaking + $TeachersAssessment;
$Overall = $Results /130*100;


if(isset($_POST['SubmitForm']))
{   
$checkBoxz= implode(",",$_POST['Progress']);  

$query="INSERT INTO examresults (FirstName, LastName, Passport, TeachersName, Date, CourseType, CourseCode, Grammar, Reading, Writing, Listening, Speaking, TeachersAssessment, Totalz, Overallz, Progress) VALUES ('$FirstName','$LastName','$Passport','$TeachersName','$Date','$CourseType','$CourseCode','$Grammar','$Reading','$Writing','$Listening','$Speaking','$TeachersAssessment',$Totalz','$Overallz','". $checkBoxz ."')";
mysqli_query($mysqli,$query) or die($mysqli->error);
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Exam Cover Sheet</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="js/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>
  </head>

<body>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="cal.php">
  <p>
    <label for="textfield"></label>
  </p>
  <table width="63%" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td width="19%"><strong>First Name:</strong></td>
      <td width="31%"><label for="textfield9"></label>
      <input type="text" name="FirstName" id="textfield9" value="<?= isset($_POST['FirstName']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['FirstName']) : '' ?>"/></td>
      <td width="50%">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Last Name:</strong></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="LastName" id="textfield10" value="<?= isset($_POST['LastName']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['LastName']) : '' ?>"/></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Passport No.:</strong></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="Passport" id="textfield11" value="<?= isset($_POST['Passport']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['Passport']) : '' ?>"/></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Teacher's Name:</strong></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="TeachersName" id="textfield13" value="<?= isset($_POST['TeachersName']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['TeachersName']) : '' ?>"/></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Date:</strong></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="Date" id="datepicker" value="<?= isset($_POST['Date']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['Date']) : '' ?>"/></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Course Type:</strong></td>
      <td><label for="select"></label>
        <select name="CourseType" id="select">
        <option value="Elementary 1">Elementary 1</option>
        <option value="Elementary 2" >Elementary 2</option>
        <option value="Elementary 3" >Elementary 3</option>
        <option value="Intermediate 1" >Intermediate 1</option>
        <option value="Intermediate 2" >Intermediate 2</option>
        <option value="Intermediate 3" >Intermediate 3</option>
        <option value="Pre-Intermediate 1">Pre-Intermediate 1</option>
        <option value="Pre-Intermediate 2" >Pre-Intermediate 2</option>
        <option value="Pre-Intermediate 3" >Pre-Intermediate 3</option>
      </select></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Course Code:</strong></td>
      <td><label for="select2"></label>
        <select name="CourseCode" id="select2">
        <option value="Elementary 1">EL1</option>
        <option value="Elementary 2" >EL2</option>
        <option value="Elementary 3" >EL3</option>
        <option value="Intermediate 1" >I1</option>
        <option value="Intermediate 2" >I2</option>
        <option value="Intermediate 3" >I3</option>
        <option value="Pre-Intermediate 1">PI1</option>
        <option value="Pre-Intermediate 2" >PI2</option>
        <option value="Pre-Intermediate 3" >PI3</option>
      </select></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="19%"><p><strong>Grammar:</strong></td>
      <td width="31%"><p><input type="text" name="Grammar" id="textfield" value="<?= isset($_POST['Grammar']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['Grammar']) : '' ?>">
        <strong>/35</strong></p></td>
      <td width="50%">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Reading:</strong></td>
      <td><p><input type="text" name="Reading" id="textfield2" value="<?= isset($_POST['Reading']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['Reading']) : '' ?>">
        <strong>/20</strong></p></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Writing:</strong></td>
      <td><p><input type="text" name="Writing" id="textfield3" value="<?= isset($_POST['Writing']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['Writing']) : '' ?>">
        <strong>/20</strong></p></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Listening:</strong></td>
      <td><p><input type="text" name="Listening" id="textfield4" value="<?= isset($_POST['Listening']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['Listening']) : '' ?>">
        <strong>/20</strong></p></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Speaking:</strong></td>
      <td><p><input type="text" name="Speaking" id="textfield5" value="<?= isset($_POST['Speaking']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['Speaking']) : '' ?>">
        <strong>/20</strong></p></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Teacher`s assessment:</strong></td>
      <td><p><input type="text" name="TeachersAssessment" id="textfield6" value="<?= isset($_POST['TeachersAssessment']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['TeachersAssessment']) : '' ?>">
        <strong>/15</strong></p></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="Totalz" id="textfield7" value="<?php echo "$Results" ?>">
      <strong>/130</strong></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="Overallz" id="textfield8" value="<?php echo "$Overall" ?>">
      <strong>%</strong></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="submit" name="Result" id="Result" value="Calculate"></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Teacher’s recommendation:</strong></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Progress[]" value="Repeat" id="CheckboxGroup1_0">
      Repeat</label>
    <br></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Progress[]" value="Progress" id="CheckboxGroup1_1">
      Progress</label>
    <br></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="SubmitForm" id="SubmitForm" value="Insert Records">
  </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you try  print your query and check in phpmyadmin sql box for error?

Comment: Yeah .. I just noticed lol 
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

An error message is showing the the query part **exactly after** the error spot.

So if you look at your query in this place you will see the missed quote

```
,$Totalz','$Overallz','". $checkBoxz ."'
```

To prevent **any possibility** of introducing such an error (let alone protection from SQL injection to which your code is severely prone), you have to use **prepared statements** for your queries. For which purpose [PDO](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#prepared) is much more useful than mysqli.

Comment: That's an increasing knowledge. Thank you